# How do I reference ID as a variable in cytoscape.js

Tags: cytoscape.js

For example, this is working:

```
cy.nodes("[id='22132']").position('x')
```

And this isn't:

```
cy.nodes("[id=targetID]").position('x')
```

How can I reference ID as a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something fancy like [Template-Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

```
cy.nodes(`[id='${variable}']`).position('x');
```

Or you can use something simple like normal string concatination:

```
cy.nodes("[id='" + variable + "']").position('x');
```

Comment: Great, if this solves your question, please accept my answer :)